# What is a decent xml cms for actionscript?

Tags: xml, sqlite, actionscript, air, typo3

My client wants a xml driven flash actionscript cms with menus, text and videos from a Typo3 CMS. Can I suggest him to use an alternative webserver when he wants to browse the site offline or is there any decdnt xml flash actionscript cms I can recommend? I've a licence for a webserver on a cd and it would be easier to put the site on a cd or any other virtual file then to provide an actionscript and sqlite solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the extension [T3flex](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/show/extension-t3flex) which provides such an abstraction between TYPO3 and AS3.

Although the extension lost a bit of momentum I still think it would be worth a try.

Comment: Does this work with xml pagetree and tt_content table offline? I need the same functionality offline. How does this differ from a standalone webserver?

Comment: I presume working offline is just a matter caching within Air. The solution above will only work reasonably, if you have online access from time to time (and cache the T3flex output accordingly).

Comment: caching means a sqlite or a similar solution? the problem would be to store the text and image in an xml subset?

Comment: I'm not to sure aboute Air's capabilities, but you should be able to save images in local storage (e.g. base64 encoded): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363234/ . text won't be a problem, I'd just leave it in the XML and read from it again

Comment: XML is a good start but how is that differ from a standalone webserver? I need to clarify this with my client?

Comment: It would have offline capabilities, with a centralized way of updating your website.

Comment: with a standalone webserver I can update virtual any distribution within a minute. An actionscript solution means to copy some of t3 functionality like stdwrap or recursion?!

Comment: I can use a batch file or an exe to start my webserver?